# Populate the python tkinter listbox with numbers only

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How can I populate my python tkinter listbox with only numbers extracted from a file, without letters, spaces, blank lines or other characters either?

```
def loadRows(self):
        creditsDigits = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
        with open("creditsSum.dstd", "r") as crSumSaved:
            creditsSaved = crSumSaved.readlines()
            for index, line in enumerate(creditsSaved):
                self.creditsListbox.insert(END, line)
                if any(list(line)) not in creditsDigits:
                        self.creditsListbox.delete(index)
```

I made up this function but it still opens every character found in the file.

Comment: It is not clear what you want.  Post some sample data and the expected result in the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

There is a default string method, called `isnumeric()` that is used to check whether a string can be converted to an integer or not.

For example, if we run the following code:

```
string = "ABC1382D5DFH"
a = "".join([item for item in string if string.isnumeric()])
print(a)
```

Output:

```
13825
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it's what you wanted (tell me if not ^^) but here s a piece of code that can help you (I think)

```
from tkinter import *
import re

def loadRows(self):
        creditsDigits = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
        with open("creditsSum.dstd", "r") as crSumSaved:
            creditsSaved = crSumSaved.readlines()

        numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', creditsSaved) #return list of str of all numbers in the file

        for number in numbers :
            self.creditsListbox.insert(END, int(number))
```

have a nice day !

Comment: Note that exception raised on the line `numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', creditsSaved)` because `creditsSaved` is a *list*, not string.

Comment: As @acw1668 said, indeed creditsSaved is a list of values from the file. You can easly correct this issue by creating a for loop to go through the list. and append every str in creditsSaved to numbers (numbers will be a list of every numbers (as str) from each index of creditsSaved)
ex : 
creditsSaved[0] = 'hello12 I m a str'
numbers[0] = '12'

Comment: Simply change `.readlines()` to `.read()`.

Comment: @David01 thanks for the answer, I modified just a bit your function and now It works as I wanted